# Present AVPlayerViewController in UITabBarController in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, avplayerviewcontroller

My code:

```
NSString *url = @"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4";
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = player;
[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In iPhone is ok but in iPad, it's lack a part of video control like image below. I don't want to add AVPlayer into view of current view controller, because it still show tabbar, lot of thing to handle (ex: click to another tab when showing video, hide video when click done, ...). Any help is appreciated

[image]

**EDIT**

It shows full video control when i remove this line ***[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];***

But i have another issue: how to force landscape mode in iPad, so i have a way is subclass AVPlayerViewController and overriding method *supportedInterfaceOrientations* but i see in [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller)

> Do not subclass AVPlayerViewController. Overriding this class’s methods is unsupported and results in undefined behavior.

So we have another way to force landscape mode in iPad?

**Update:**

Subclass AVPlayerViewController and overriding method *supportedInterfaceOrientations* worked but i think maybe have any problem in future like:

1. Not work in later iOS
2. Rejected by Apple when submit app to store.
3. ...

Comment: Embed the player controller in a UINavigationController and present it.

Comment: bad me, i just need remove this like and it work. `[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];` +1 for you @New16, your way is correct too